# Want to create a new array in for loop every time Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a material dynamic table which has inline dropdown fields which can be edited an saved
Scenario :
First Row contains Dropdown name EmployeeName list which loads from an array list
Now the Second row should load from a different array list list for same dropdown EmployeeName
even though the values in both rows are same

So suppose we have 10 rows, so i should have the same values but 10 different list for every row in the Material table

And lastly all this array list variable names should be able to be used in HTML for binding the dropdown

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="EmpName" class="ColW110">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="ColW110"> Employee Names </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index;" class="ColW110">
                            <div class="ColW110">
                                <mat-form-field class="ColW80pr">
                                    <mat-select id="ddlEmpName" >
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let emp of empNameList" [value]="emp.EmpID">
                                            {{emp.EmpName}}</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
```

so the aim is to create multiple arrays with same values based upon the number of rows

Comment: so if my understanding is correct you want 10 rows with 10 dropdowns made out of `EmployeeName` ?

Comment: Yes i want 10 dropdowns each dropdown is mapped to one row, but the 10 dropdowns should load from 10 different list even though the values of the list are same. EmpID. EmpName.

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts file create a method or a getter that returns a copy of the array.

```
get newEmpNameList() {
    return [...this.empNameList];
}
```

Then in your template you can replace `let emp of empNameList` with `let emp of newNameList`.

Heres an article explaining the [...Array] syntax and other ways to copy arrays:   https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/

Comment: Hey Aditya could you give me some feedback on if my suggestion worked?

Comment: Nice, could you in that case mark my answer as the solution (best answer)? That way I'll get points for it.

Comment: I am still not getting values in the dropdown though can you have a look what is wrong with the below code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="EmpName" class="ColW110">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="ColW110"> Employee Names </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index;" class="ColW110">
                            <div class="ColW110">
                                <mat-form-field class="ColW80pr">
                                    <mat-select id="ddlEmpName" >
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let emp of element.EmpDet.EmpNameList" [value]="emp.EmpID">
                                            {{emp.EmpName}}</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
```

Actually still my dropdowns are not getting values in HTML but .ts i can see the data for the same.

Comment: Can you also post the .ts code for "element.EmpDet.EmpNameList?